# Splitting Memo line into other two memos

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have line in memo something like

**something**=**anything**

How can I split by omitting = s**omething and** **anything** into memo2 and memo3

memo1 = **something**=**anything**

*and after split*

memo2 = something

memo3 = anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memo line split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754500/memo-line-split)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pos` to find the position of the equal sign, and use `copy` to pull out the substrings you need.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : string;
  P : integer;
begin
  // get text from Memo1

  S := Memo1 . Text;

  // find the position of the equal sign

  P := pos ( '=', S );

  // Put left substring in Memo2

  Memo2 . Text := copy ( S, 1, P - 1 );

  // Put right substring in Memo3

  Memo3 . Text := copy ( S, P + 1, maxint );

end;
```

Comment: I was experimenting similar method to implement in listbox . for adding Memo2.text as listbox items . but it comes single item in list box whereas Memo1 has more than one line. whereas i can not use s:=Memo1.lines; i get error incompatible types 'String' and Tstrings';

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with your issues with ListBox and assigning Lines to a string.  But first, would you say the answer I've given answers the question you've given?  If so please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Then, you can ask a new question about ListBox and Lines.  Tell us how you are expecting your code to work.  And then show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes previous answer really helped thanks for that .. Now i am trying to add memo1.lines as listbox items , whereas memo1 has similar lines  **something=anything, trays=fruits** and so on there are lot of lines like this .. how can i only add memo line text before **=** like we get both of them separately in two memos in previous helped answer .

Comment: so far i tried **Listbox1.items.addstrings(Memo1.lines);** and list items are as  **something=anything, trays=fruits** and so on ... but how to get only **something , trays**, and so on in listbox but not **=anything, =fruits.**

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it as correct.  Meanwhile, you should create a NEW question regarding the issues with ListBox1.  There you can tell us what you're trying to accomplish, and you can show us the source code that you've tried so far.

Comment: i can not post new question as i get message **You have reached your question limit** .. please help me here

Comment: I need help in this matter please.. i have lines in memo something like this 

**something = anything** ,

**Tray = Fruits**

How can i split and delet **=anything** and get only **something** as List box item and similarly for other list items from memo

memo1 = **something = anything** ,

memo1 = **Tray = Fruit**

List Items should be as

**something**  ,

**Tray**

Comment: Do you know how to use a FOR loop?

Comment: I am learning sir from you all experts and from this great site. please help me to solve my problem.